# Vue js show hide element on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am new in vue js. I want to show hide elements on click.
So that What I can do -
make a property in data object like

```
isHidden: false
```

and add a mehtod like

```
showHide(){
return this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
}
```

And bind the showHide method on click event like

```
<li @click="showHide">Some text</a>
```

But the problem is- if there are several list items binding the same click event,
all lists will be shown on click, or all will hide. But I want the
target element will only show or hide by click.

How can I do this, please?

Comment: Can you not store the `isHidden` flag on each item? What does this list of items look like?

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on some of these answers, you want to keep track of what's hidden and not hidden in your `data` object using a `isHidden` flag or similar.

Then when you loop through your object using `v-for`, conditionally set the `isHidden` property for the current item when it's clicked.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    itemList: [{
        "id": 1,
        "text": "first item",
        "isHidden": false
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "second item",
        "isHidden": true,

      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "text": "third item",
        "isHidden": false,

      },
    ],
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in itemList" :key="item.id">
      <button @click="item.isHidden = !item.isHidden">
        <span v-if="item.isHidden">Show</span>
        <span v-else>Hide</span>
      </button>
      <span v-if="!item.isHidden">{{ item.text }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some data to determine what element you want show/hide. For example: id, index of each element

```
<button v-for="(i, ind) in listElement" @click="toggleElement(ind)" :key="ind">
  Toggle {{ i }}
</button>

<p v-for="(i, ind) in listElementShow" :key="ind">
  Element: {{ i }}
</p>
```

Logic:

```
  data() {
    return {
      listElement: [ { name: 1, isShow: true}, { name: 2, isShow: true}],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    listElementShow() {
      return this.listElement.filter(e => e.isShow); 
    }
  }
  methods: {
    toggleElement(index) {
      this.listElement[index].isShow = !this.listElement[index].isShow;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
<template>
    <ul class="list-with-hidden-items">
        <li
            v-for="item in list"
            :key="item.id"
            @click="showHide(item.id)"
        >
            {{ item.text }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        hidden: {}
    }),
    methods: {
        showHide(id) {
            this.$set(this.hidden, id, !this.hidden[id]);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and then you can render where you want your item to be shown like this:

```
<div v-if="!this.hidden.item1">I am shown because of item1 is not hidden</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamically bound classObject to do such a thing.
See [Class and Style Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-lalande-sugk0?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

```
<template>
  <div @click="showHide()" :class="{ isHidden: isHidden }">
    <p>This is a thing</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      isHidden: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showHide() {
      this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
.isHidden {
  background-color: grey;
}
div {
  background-color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle inside your `showHide` method, to simplify your code.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I just did this snippet quick and dirty to show that he can pass his target to his function.

Comment: You should avoid directly modifying the DOM like this if you're using Vue. Use class and style bindings instead: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: @dave Good call, updated.